# Haskell, how to replace nested if with a case-of statement?

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to learn haskell and I'm solving some simple programming challenges. So my current problem right now is just printing some text based on the value being passed:

```hs
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  if n `mod` 2 > 0
      then putStrLn "Weird"
      else if n > 1 && n < 6
          then putStrLn "Not Weird"
          else if n > 5 && n < 21
              then putStrLn "Weird"
              else putStrLn "Not Weird"
```

However I think this is fairly ugly, is there someway I could replace the nested if structure with a more elegant pattern matching?

I've tried:

```hs
main :: IO()
main = do
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    case n of
        n `mod` 2 /= 0 -> putStrLn "Weird"
        n >= 2 && N <= 5 -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
        n >= 6 && N <= 20 -> putStrLn "Weird"
        n > 20 -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
```

but I get a compile error.

Edit: Final solution

```hs
check :: Int -> String
check n
    | (n `mod` 2 /= 0) = "Weird"
    | (n >= 2) && (n <= 5) = "Not Weird"
    | (n >= 6) && (n <= 20) = "Weird"
    | otherwise = "Not Weird"

main :: IO()
main = do
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    putStrLn (check n)
```

Comment: `case` expects patterns, ``n `mod` 2 /= 0``, etc. are *not* patterns.

Comment: right, so how would one go about doing this? guards?

Comment: `putStrLn $ if odd n || inRange (6,20) n then "Weird" else "Not Weird"`

Comment: @DanielWagner even though yours is shorter, my objective was not to come up with the shortest possible version, but rather to understand the difference between `if..else` statements, `guards` and `case..of`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [*`case` expression* [Haskell-report]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) deals with patterns. An expression like `` n `mod` 2 /= 0 `` is *not* a pattern.

I propose to define a helper function, and use *guards*:

```
tmp :: Int -> String
tmp n | n `mod` 2 /= 0 = "Weird"
      | n >= 2 && N <= 5 = "Not Weird"
      | n >= 6 && N <= 20 = "Weird"
      | n > 20 = "Not Weird"
      | otherwise = …
```

You will still need to define a value for the `otherwise` case, in case `n <= 0`.

We can then use this with:

```
main = do
    n <- readLn
    putStrLn (tmp n)
```

Comment: n == 1 should be catched by the first case, it is an odd number, however I replaced otherwise with _ and throws an error, do you know why could this be?

Comment: @OscarFranco: you can not write `otherwise = _`, since Haskell expects a string. You thus will need to specify a string, like `"Weird"` for example.

Comment: no, I wrote `| _ = "Weird"` since I learned that _ is a valid identifier

Comment: @OscarFranco: no `_` is a *pattern* :). So you can not use it in a guard. Which expects expressions of type `Bool`. In fact `otherwise` is just an alias for `True`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use guards if you have boolean expressions (conditions), instead of actual patterns.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    case () of
       _ | n `mod` 2 /= 0 -> putStrLn "Weird"
         | n >= 2 && n <= 5 -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
         | n >= 6 && n <= 20 -> putStrLn "Weird"
         | n > 20 -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
```

Consider using `otherwise` in the last case: assuming you want to catch everything else, it's faster and suppresses a GHC warning about non-exhaustiveness.

A "multiway if" can also be used as an alternative, but it requires an extension.

Answer (score 1):

"multiway if" was mentioned in chi's answer but not explained and I think it's useful to know about for such cases. Enabling [the `MultiWayIf` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#multi-way-if-expressions) (e.g. by writing `{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}` at the top of the file) allows you to write

```
if | (n `mod` 2 /= 0) -> putStrLn "Weird"
   | (n >= 2) && (n <= 5) -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
   | (n >= 6) && (n <= 20) -> putStrLn "Weird"
   | otherwise -> putStrLn "Not Weird"
```